# Django extend common variable or block in child templates

Tags: python, django-templates, jinja2

I have a common variable or block in base template that i want to extend in child templates, how can i achieve that? I have following code.

base.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            {% block page_title %} {% endblock %}
        </title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="{% block page_title %} {% endblock %}" />
        ...
    </head>
<body>
<h1> {% block page_title %} {% endblock %} </h1>
...
```

my_page.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block page_title %}
    Page title goes here
{% endblock %}
```

When i run this code i get the following error
'block' tag with name 'page_title' appears more than once

Comment: AFAIK, blocks have to be unique. Your block `page_title` appears twice.

Comment: How can i achieve the solution?

Comment: in each `view`, set a context variable with the value of page title in it.

Comment: As @SachinKukreja states, use the same context variable in all those places and make sure your views provide it properly. You might provide a default value in the template not to ever leave it empty.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you find yourself wanting for a value to appear twice in a template it smells like that data should be provided in your rendering context.

There are many options for that, but the simplest is just to provide a `page_title` context parameter when rendering the template:

```
def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {
        'page_title': 'Your Page Title',
    })
```

And then use it in your template as any other template variable: `{{ page_title }}`